# Manipulating the subscription to an observable in one component affects the subscription in another component

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have a menu service, which provides observables to my components. I have two components that need to use this data. A Side Menu component (with nested child elements) and a menu editor (that just wants a flat list of all menu elements with no children). All my code was working fine, until I tried to flatten the menu structure for the editor. Upon opening the menu editor, the side menu loses all the nested parent-child relationships.

I have confirmed that my flattening function is causing it, if I remove it, then it doesn't happen. If I go to another page, it doesn't happen.

How can I set this up such that if I manipulate the data from the observable (by essentially creating new objects) in one component that it doesn't affect the other components.

**menu.service.ts**

```
export class MenuService {
  private _loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  private _nestedMenu$ = new BehaviorSubject<MenuItem[]>([]);
  private _get$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getAllMenuItems();
  }


  getAllMenuItems() {
    return this.http.get<MenuItem[]>(`${environment.privateApiUrl}/System/GetAllMenuItemList`)
      .subscribe({
        next: (result => {
          this._nestedMenu$.next(result);
        }),
        error: ( catchError(<T>(error: any, result?: T) => {
          console.log(error);
          return of(result as T);
        }))
      });
  }

  get nestedMenu$() { return this._nestedMenu$.asObservable(); }
  get loading$() {return this._loading$.asObservable(); }


}
```

**side-menu.component.ts**

```
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  loading = false;
  menuItems: MenuItem[];

  constructor(public sideNavService: SideNavService, private http: HttpClient, private menuService: MenuService) {
    this.menuService.nestedMenu$.subscribe({
      next: ((value) => {
        this.loading = true;
        const menuArray: MenuItem[] = [];
        for (const node of value) {
          if (node.parent == null) {
            menuArray.push(node);
          }
        }
        this.menuItems = menuArray;
        this.loading = false;
      }),
      complete: (() => {
      })
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**menu-manager.component.ts**

```
export class MenuManagerComponent implements OnInit {
  collapsed = false;
  faPen = faPen;
  fullMenuList: MenuItem[];
  menuItems: [{depth: number, menuItem: MenuItem}?] = [];
  constructor(private menuService: MenuService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuService.nestedMenu$.subscribe({
      next: ((value) => {
        this.fullMenuList = value;
        this.flattenMenu(this.fullMenuList.filter(x => x.parent === null),0);
      })
    });
  }

  flattenMenu(menuItems: MenuItem[], depth: number) {
    for (const menuItem of menuItems) {
      this.menuItems.push({depth, menuItem});
      this.flattenMenu(menuItem.children, depth + 1);
      menuItem.children = null;
    }
  }

}
```

[image: Behaviour in Angular]

Comment: Different subscriptions are totally independent, you don't need to do anything about it.

However, the value emitted by the behavior subject is the same for all subscribers. So if any subscriber *mutates* this value in any way it will inevitably be reflected in other subscribers.

In your code snippets I don't see any value mutation though. Maybe it happens somewhere else in the code?

Comment: `menuItem.children = null;` could be it. Not at my machine right now but I have a feeling that could be it.